# How best to mix promises and event emitters in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

Feel like there is some code smell in the below:

```
  const Promise = require('bluebird');
  function initServer() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var server = require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {
                res.writeHead(200);
                res.write('pick a side');
                res.end();
            });

            server.listen(config.port, function () {
                logger.log('initServer: http server up on: ' + config.port);
                return resolve(server);
            });
        });
    }

initServer().then(function () {
    logger.log('we up');
});
```

What is the preferred way to structure the the promise given the above?

Comment: What do you mean by preferred? What is your intent?

Comment: i guess
initServer.then(function () {
    logger.log('we up');
});
should be 
initServer().then(function () {
    logger.log('we up');
});

Comment: Assumed that was just a typo, but yeah, if it's throwing an error... OP didn't mention any exception.

Comment: was just a typo

Comment: Too bad no one commented, I'm in the same boat: smells fishy. The main issue is that the promise block finishes executing but it is still pending. TypeScript will complain about this if you try to lock down the return type. One of the biggest problems is that the promise may never resolve and you can end up accumulating LOTS of pending promises. I throw in a timeout, but it is still a fishy combination of patterns. If you find an answer (4 years later! please DM me...)